# transfer every second item in list (python)

Tags: python

I have a list `a = [[1, 6, 5, 9], [], [], [4, -3]]`

I want to move every second item (6,9 and -3) from a non empty list into a new one. The new list should look like this `b = [[6, 9], [], [], [-3]]` The items I moved should be removed from the first list. So far I have this but I don't know how to remove them nicely:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i]:
        b[i] = a[i][1::2]
```

Is there any way to do this nicely (maybe list comprehension)? I use python3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, straight forward:

```
b = [c[1::2] for c in a]
```

Instead of removing items, create a new list with the other half:

```
a = [c[::2] for c in a]
```